# Permission to ORG/REPO denied to USER

Tags: git, github

I am getting `Permission to ORG/REPO denied to USER` just recently whenever I try and push commits to github, where `USER` is not me! I can't even find that `USER` anywhere in ~/.gitconfig or ~/.git-credentials.

I checked my ~/.ssh folder as well to double check if my keys got compromised. I even grepped for `USER` everywhere to no avail.

Where is that coming from? Like I'd have expected `USER` to be my account not someone else. I checked that `USER` on github and they're one of the contributors in one repository that I contribute to. But I was pushing to a different repository they have no access to.

Comment: Step 1: look at the *url* you're using for `git push`, e.g., `git remote show -v`. Step 2: if it's https, look at your credential helpers; if it's ssh, look at your ssh keys. To look at your ssh keys, use `ssh -Tv git@github.com`: keep Git out of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where USER is not me

That points to an HTTPS URL, with the wrong credentials cached in it:

```
git config --global credential.helper
xxx
# replace xxx with the value returned by git config
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https"| git credential-xxx get
```

To remove the wrong user:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=WrongUser"| git credential-xxx erase
```